# Compiled a Kernel (2.6.39-rc1), where is the corresponding initramfs?

Tags: kernel, grub, initramfs

as I've already wrote in the topic, I compiled a new Kernel with `make defconfig`, the `bzImage` is where it there, so is `vmlinux.bin`. I've installed modules with `make modules_install`.

Now, what is the next step? should I rename `bzImage` to my liking and put it into `/boot`? And how do I create an initramfs?

`vmlinux.bin` is executable, is that my Kernel?

I'm using GRUB, and I'm quite familiar with using and configuring it. But I'm having a hard time putting the kernel together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you've made `make modules_install`, the next steps are:

- `make install` this will take care to move the bzImage, System.map and .config to /boot with the right names, e.g. `config-2.6.39-rc1`, `System.map-2.6.39-rc1`, etc...
- the next step is to build the initramfs. That depends on the distro. On a debian-like distro, it would be `mkinitramfs -c -k 2.6.39-rc1`. A RH like distro that would be `mkinitrd /boot/initrd-2.6.39-rc1.img 2.6.39-rc1`
- Add the new kernel to your boot loader, on a modern distro, that would be a simple `update-grub`

Note: `make defconfig` may generate a kernel that lacks the proper drivers for your hardware. Safer alternatives would be to either copy the .config of your currently running kernel (look in /boot or /proc/config.gz), or to manually determine the necessary drivers by 'hand' and running a `make xconfig`

Note2: `-rc1` is *very* fresh, expect it to contain bugs.

Comment: I know about freshness, etc. This is just a test, though. I'll configure with `make gconfig` later.

Comment: Wouldn't using high-level distribution-specific tools eg. Debian's `kernel-package` (though it seems to not have the favor of Debian's kernel packaging team) be more efficient? This would automate the lower level steps.

Comment: @Faheem I does, but I personaly found easier to learn the low level steps, so that you don't have to relearn everything every time you switch to another distro. I guess it depends on how many different distros you deal with on a regular basis.

Comment: @Frederik: good point

Comment: Also, this Kernel is not meant to make too much sense. It's just for testing out stuff.

Comment: Also, when running `make allmodconfig`, what happens to the options that can't be built as a module? Is 'y' assumed?

Comment: Yes, if it's a Y/N switch, it will be compiled in.

Comment: I compiled with `allmodconfig` but the kernel still won't boot. Anyway, `make install` did install the kernel and create the initramfs image.